# Granting a user with access to multiple views and adding rows without seeing everything

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create multiple users and each one of them should have read access to a lot of views.

Also, I want these users to be able to insert data into a certain table without having any direct access to said table - is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into granting specific rights to specific users on MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach-

suppose you have a table called test_table-

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
fname VARCHAR(50),
age INT
)
```

Now create a view from this table-

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT * FROM test_table;
```

Now create user "user1" and assign rights as per below-

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON zafar.insert_view TO user1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1';
```

Note: Here I have provided rights globally for an example but on production server you need to provide rights to specific server instead of %.

Now connect by user "user1" and insert row as per below-

```
INSERT INTO test_view (fname,age) VALUES('zafar',35);
```